# Why is my random generator only generating 0's?

Tags: java

Everytime I run my program to get the sum of the two randomly generated integers, the result is always 0 + 0. Please let me know what I am missing.

```
public void question() {

    System.out.println("What is " + Random1 + "+" + Random2 + "?");
    userAnswer = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You entered: " + userAnswer);
}

public void actualAnswer() {

    Answer = (Random1 + Random2);

    System.out.println("The Correct Answer is: " + Answer);

    if(userAnswer==(Answer)) {
        System.out.println("You answered correctly!");
    }   
    else {
        System.out.println("You answered incorrectly");

    }
}


private void random1() {

    Random1 = random.nextInt(10) + 1;

}

private void random2() {

    Random2 = random.nextInt(10) + 1;

}
```

Comment: Try and avoid using uppercase for variable names, this is pretty confusing. Also, what are `random`, `Random1`, `Random2` and `Answer`? Your code doesn't show.

Comment: Because you are not calling random1() and random2() methods before assigning values to 'Answer'. As @fge suggested, read about Java naming conventions.

Comment: @Adi Thanks. I called them in the question method and it's working now

Answer (score 0):

Although your context is not very clear to me, what I understood from your question is yo are unable to generate random number for sum. I have edited a part and my solution gives you sum of random generated integers. Hope this will be a help :)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomGenerator {

     int randomInt1 =0;
     int randomInt2 =0;
     Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
     int userAnswer;
     int answer;
    /*public void question() {

        System.out.println("What is " + randomInt1 + "+" + randomInt2 + "?");
        userAnswer = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You entered: " + userAnswer);
    }*/

    public void actualAnswer() {
        answer = (random1() + random2());
        System.out.println(" numbers generated are: "+ random1()+", "+random2());
        System.out.println("The Sum is: " + answer);

      /*  if(userAnswer==(answer)) {
            System.out.println("You answered correctly!");
        }   
        else {
            System.out.println("You answered incorrectly");

        }*/
    }


    private int random1() {
          Random randomGenerator = new Random();
          for(int i =0; i<3; i++){

          randomInt1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
          }
          return randomInt1;
    }

    private int random2() {

         Random randomGenerator = new Random();
         for(int i =0; i<3; i++){

             randomInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);

         }
         return randomInt2;
    }
public static void main(String a[]){
    RandomGenerator rg=new RandomGenerator();
    rg.actualAnswer();
}
}
```